# Unable to update firewall rules for mysqlserver from app service

Tags: mysql, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to update vnet rules for mysqlserver from app service.
App Service and mysqlserver tf code is like below:

```
module "app_service" {
  for_each = coalesce(var.app_service, {})
  source   = "company/org/app-service/azurerm"
  version  = "1.1"
  
  location            = var.environment_hosting_region
  resource_group_name = var.environment_resource_groups
  tags                = try(each.value.tags, local.tags)
  name                = try(each.value.name, null)
}

variable "mysqlserver" {
  description = "Map of mysqlserver objects"
  type        = any
  default     = null
}

module "mysqlserver" {
  for_each = coalesce(var.mysqlserver, {})
  source   = "company/org/mysqlserver/azurerm"
  version  = "1.1"

  administrator_login            = try(each.value.administrator_login, null)
  administrator_login_password   = try(each.value.administrator_login_password, null)
  backup_retention_days          = try(each.value.backup_retention_days, null)
  charset                        = try(each.value.charset, "utf8")
  collation                      = try(each.value.collation, "utf8_unicode_ci")
  create_mode                    = try(each.value.create_mode, "Default")
  creation_source_server_id      = try(each.value.creation_source_server_id, null)
  database_names                 = try(each.value.database_names, [])
  default_rules                  = try(each.value.default_rules, true)
  enable_account_admins          = try(each.value.enable_account_admins, true)
  enable_threat_detection_policy = try(each.value.enable_threat_detection_policy, true)
  geo_redundant_backup           = try(each.value.geo_redundant_backup, false)
  identity_type                  = try(each.value.identity_type, null)
  location                       = var..environment_hosting_region
  mysql_version                  = try(each.value.mysql_version, null)
  name                           = try(each.value.name, null)
  resource_group_name       = var..environment_resource_groups
  restore_point_in_time     = try(each.value.restore_point_in_time, null)
  sku_name                  = try(each.value.sku_name, null)
  storage_mb                = try(each.value.storage_mb, null)
  tags                      = try(each.value.tags, local.tags)
  threat_log_retention_days = try(each.value.threat_log_retention_days, 7)
  vnet_rules                = [for subnet in try(each.value.subnet_ref, []) : data.azurerm_subnet.subnet[subnet].id]
  nsg_rules                 = try(each.value.nsg_rules, [])
  firewall_rules = each.value.app_service_ref != null ? module.app_service[each.value.app_service_ref].firewall_rules : null 
}
```

I get multiple errors as like below:

```
│ Error: waiting for create/update of Firewall Rule: (Name "rule_x.y.z.170" / Server Name "u2zuuhjjsddm002" / Resource Group "mysqlserver-rg"): Code="InvalidParameterValue" Message="Invalid value given for parameter 
'{0}'. Specify a valid parameter value."
│
│   with module.mysqlserver["patterns_default_mysqlserver"].azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule.firewall_rules[53],
│   on .terraform/modules/mysqlserver/main.tf line 69, in resource "azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule" "firewall_rules":
│   69: resource "azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule" "firewall_rules" {
```

Mysqlserver  module code as per below:

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  firewall_rules = concat(local.tfe_firewall.tfe_servers, local.default_fw_rules, var.firewall_rules)
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_server" "mysql" {
  name                             = var.name
  resource_group_name              = var.resource_group_name
 
   ssl_enforcement_enabled          = true
  ssl_minimal_tls_version_enforced = "TLS1_2"
  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identity_type != null ? [""] : []
    content {
      type = var.identity_type
    }
  }
  threat_detection_policy {
    enabled              = var.enable_threat_detection_policy
    email_account_admins = var.enable_account_admins
    retention_days       = var.threat_log_retention_days
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_database" "databases" {
  count               = length(var.database_names)
  name                = element(var.database_names, count.index)
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  charset             = var.charset
  collation           = var.collation
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_virtual_network_rule" "subnets" {
  count               = length(var.vnet_rules)
  name                = "subnet-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  subnet_id           = element(var.vnet_rules, count.index)
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "mysql-nsg" {
  count                       = length(var.nsg_rules)
  name                        = "NSG-MYSQL-${count.index}"
  priority                    = 200+count.index
  direction                   = "Outbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "3306"
  source_address_prefix       = var.nsg_rules[count.index]["source_address_prefix"]
  destination_address_prefix  = "Sql"
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = var.nsg_rules[count.index]["network_security_group_name"]
}

resource "azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule" "firewall_rules" {
  count               = local.firewall_rules == [] ? 0 : length(local.firewall_rules)
  name                = local.firewall_rules[count.index]["name"]
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.mysql.name
  start_ip_address    = local.firewall_rules[count.index]["start_ip_address"]
  end_ip_address      = local.firewall_rules[count.index]["end_ip_address"]
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_mysql_server.mysql
  ]
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "firewall_rules" {
  description = "List of firewall rules to be attached to the MySQL server."
  type = list(object({
    name             = string
    start_ip_address = string
    end_ip_address   = string
  }))
  default = []
}

variable "nsg_rules" {
  description = "NSG Rules"
  type = list(object({
    source_address_prefix       = string
    network_security_group_name = string
  }))
  default = []
}

variable "vnet_rules" {
  description = "List of subnets to add to vnet_rules"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

variable "charset" {
  description = "Specifies the Charset for the MySQL Database, which needs to be a valid MySQL Charset. Available option are (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html)."
  type        = string
  default     = "utf8"
}

variable "collation" {
  description = "Specifies the Collation for the MySQL Database, which needs to be a valid MySQL Collation. Available option are (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html)."
  type        = string
  default     = "utf8_unicode_ci"
}

variable "default_rules" {
  description = "Variable to control whether to turn on default rules"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
```

Unable to understand what is the issue and how can it be resolved.

Any guidance shall be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be because of `azurerm_mysql_firewall_rule` resource. Appears to be because of `local.firewall_rules` input, check `54th` rule. 
My 2 cents:: `local.firewall_rules == [] ? 0 : length(local.firewall_rules)` is a bad idea. It's better like `length(local.firewall_rules) > 0 ? length(local.firewall_rules) : 0`

Comment: Thanks @harshavmb but may I know why it is a bad idea ? Apologies if I am asking silly question, trying to understand,